# Undefined parameters in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am very new to javascript and i've been trying to make a simple function that calculates the total amount of money i spend in a week depending on the money i spend every day but i keep getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: numdays is not defined

```
var amount=calculateamount(7,20);

function calculateamount(numdays, avgmoney) 
{
   return numdays*avgmoney;
    }
```

I found the mistake but i have another question. How do i use the Number function and the isNaN function in the code? Is it like this?

```
return numdays*avgmoney; 
isNaN(calculateamount(numdays, avgmoney));
```

Comment: That looks correct... What error do you get and where?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: what is the *exact* error you are getting?

Comment: The error i'm getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: numdays is not defined

Comment: @KatyK And where’s the code necessary to reproduce this error?

Comment: @Xufox In my code haven't i defined the 'numdays'?

Comment: @KatyK Yes, you have. The code you’ve shown is working. That’s why we’ve been asking you for the code that _reproduces the error_.

Comment: @Xufox Something was wrong with my browser,i don't get that error anymore, thanks! I have another question, how do i use the Number function and the isNaN function in the code? Is it like this? return numdays*avgmoney;  isNaN(calculateamount(numdays, avgmoney));

Comment: @KatyK Post a new question rather than editing this one.

Comment: Please invest some time in learning how to use a debugger to go through the code line by line so you can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan where can i find more information about a debugger?

Comment: The usual places; [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+javascript&oq=how+to+debug+javascript), [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+debug+javascript), [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+debug+javascript&t=hf&ia=qa). Here's something on Stack Overflow from a long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/988363/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks. Can you help me with my second question?

Comment: I'd suggest looking these things up in documentation. I find MDN to be the best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number. Try things out; put things in different orders and see how that affects your output. I find that's the best way to learn, rather than getting the answers spoonfed to you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct.

```js
var amount=calculateamount(7,20);
console.log('The amount is', amount);

function calculateamount(numdays, avgmoney) 
{
   return numdays*avgmoney;
}
```

I added console.log to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. Please check the simple HTML below where I used your function to return the correct value.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var amount=calculateamount(7,20);
alert(amount);
function calculateamount(numdays, avgmoney) 
{
   return numdays*avgmoney;
} 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```